# replaceAll Dangling metacharacter

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a string, say `1++++----2` and I want to replace `++++----` with a certain string, say `string`.
The I use the java function `replaceAll`, but it keep warning **Dangling metacharacter** every time I use it:

```
mystring.replaceAll("++++----", "string");
```

Comment: If you are using fixed string replacement, use `replace` method

Comment: Looking at the previous question, it seems that you are approaching the problem the wrong way.

Comment: yes, it works. I think that replace only work with char, not string

Answer (score 3):

Escape the `+`, only the first or all doesn't matter here.

```
String str = "1+++---2";
str = str.replaceAll("\\+\\+\\+---", "");
System.out.println(str);
```

Output:

```
12
```

Or use `replaceAll`as it's meant to be used:

```
str = str.replaceAll("[+-]", "");
```

Answer (score 2):

`replaceAll`'s first argument takes a regualr expression and `+` have special meaning in regualr expression. Escape `+` to make it work properly .

```
mystring.replaceAll("\\+\\+\\+\\+----", "string");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use following regex :

```
mystring.replaceAll("\\++-+", "string")
```

Since `+` is a regex character you need to escape it.so here in `"\\++-+"` the first part `\\+` will match the character `+` literally and the second `+` will match 1 or more combination of character `+` and the rest is `-+` which will match 1 or more `-`.

Answer (score 0):

When you replace a fixed string, you need a `replace` function:

```
String mystring  = "1++++----2";
System.out.println(mystring.replace("++++----", "string"));
```

See [demo](http://ideone.com/f2MoZb)

Otherwise, you need a regex with `replaceAll`.

```
System.out.println(mystring.replaceAll("[+]+-+", "string"));
```

Note that you do not need to escape the `+` inside a regex character class, which is convenient in Java.